# Python 3.3.3 TypeError : Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been trying to program a Mad-Libs Simulator in Python 3.3.3 and I have been receiving the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/RuzHayes_Laptop/Desktop/Programming:Design/Programs/Python Mad Libs Program 000.py", line 80, in <module>
templates=[("The"+" "+adj+" "+n+" "+v+" "+adv+pun),(adj+" "+pluralize(n)+' '+(v[:len(v)-1])+" "+adv+pun)]
TypeError: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly
```

In the following code:

```
print("Welcome!")
print("When you would like to try out ")
print("Python Mad Libs Program, Prototype000,")
begin=input("press the enter/return key.")

print()
print()
print("Initializing befuddlement...")
print()

import random
sentenceCap=35
sentenceBottom=25
numOfSentences=random.randint(sentenceBottom,sentenceCap)
caps={"a":"A","b":"B","c":"C","d":"D",'e':'E','f':'F','g':'G','h':'H','i':'I','j':'J','k':'K','l':'L','m':'M','n':'N','o':'O','p':'P','q':'Q','r':'R','s':'S','t':'T','u':'U','v':'V','w':'W','x':'X','y':'Y','z':'Z'}
tempstore=[" "]*numOfSentences
irregplrls={'child':'children','ox':'oxen','moose':'moose'}
def testforoo(x):
    for j in range(0,len(x)):
        if j+1<=len(x) and x[j:j+1]=='oo'.lower():
            return True
    return False
def pluralize(x):
    l=len(x)
    for i in irregplrls:
        if i == x:
            return irregplrls[x]
    if x[l-1]=="y":
        return x[:l-1]+"ies"
    elif x[l-1]=="s" and x[l-2]=="u":
        return x[:l-2]+"i"
    elif x[l-1] in ('s','x'):
        return x+"es"
    elif x[-2:] in ('ch','sh'):
        return x+"es"
    elif 'f'==x[l-1] or x[l-2]:
        if 'f'==x[l-1]:
            return x[:l-1] + 'ves'
        elif 'f'==x[l-2]:
            return x[:l-2]+"ves"
    elif testforoo(x)!=False:
        return x[:testforoo(x)-2]+'ee'+x[testforoo(x):]
    else:
        return x+'s'

print()
print("Retrieving craploads of words...") 
print()

verb=["moves","jumps", "hides","sniffs","gazes","sneezes","calls"]
noun=["rabbit","dog","cat","otter","seal","elephant","fox",'baby','moose','octopus']
adjec=["happy","angry","cute","enormous","elegant","annoying"]
adver=["merrily","frustratedly","incoherently","morosely","peppily",'exuberantly']
endpunct=[".","!"]



print()
print("Simulating human grammar-speak...")
print()
print()

for i000 in range(0,numOfSentences):
    v=random.choice(verb)
    n=random.choice(noun)
    adj=random.choice(adjec)
    adv=random.choice(adver)
    pun=random.choice(endpunct)
    askinput=random.randint(0,round(numOfSentences/5))
    whichinput=random.randint(0,3)
    if askinput==0:
        if whichinput==0:
            n=input("Please input a noun. ")
        elif whichinput==1:
            v=input("Please input a verb. ")
        elif whichinput==2:
            adj=input("Please input an adjective. ")
        elif whichinput==3:
            adv=input("Please input an adverb. ")
    templates=[("The"+" "+adj+" "+n+" "+v+" "+adv+pun),(adj+" "+pluralize(n)+' '+(v[:len(v)-1])+" "+adv+pun)]
    final=templates[random.randint(0,len(templates)-1)]
    if final[:1]==final[:1].lower():
           final=caps[final[:1]]+final[1:]
    tempstore[i000]=final

print()
print()
print("Producing proof of illiteracy...")
print()
print()

for i001 in range(0,len(tempstore)):
    sent=tempstore[i001]
    print(sent)
```

I am very confused and I need help. I have now found the problem to be in the end of the pluralize definition, but otherwise I am very confused. The program worked until I changed pluralize to account for certain nouns not being correctly pluralized.

I will appreciate any help you can give me. I have only been programming for about a month now and this is the hardest program I have ever attempted.

Thank you and Merry Christmas! That is, of course, if you celebrate Christmas.

Comment: Obviously one the objects you attempting to insert into the string in `None`.

Comment: `for i000 in...`  and `for i0001`... Oh god, why these names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def testforoo(x):
    for j in range(0,len(x)):
        if j+1<=len(x) and x[j:j+1]=='oo'.lower():
            return True
    return False
```

is

```
def testforoo(x):
    for j in range(0,len(x)):
        if x[j]=='oo'.lower():
            return True
    return False
```

because if `len(x)` is 4, then `j` runs from 0 to 3 and `j+1` from 1 to 4, then `j+1` always <= `len(x)`  .

it is also

```
def testforoo(x):
    return any(x[j]=='oo'.lower() for j in range(0,len(x)))
```

The reason of the error is when `pluralize(n)` returns `None` (I don't know in which case), the addition of `None` to a string can be processed.

If you use the formatting with `%s`  (or with `format`), there won't be the problem anymore.

I improved your code at certain places. See:

```
begin=input("Welcome!\n"
            "When you would like to try out\n"
            "Python Mad Libs Program, Prototype000,"
            "press the enter/return key.")

print("\nInitializing befuddlement...")

import random
sentenceCap=35
sentenceBottom=25
numOfSentences=random.randint(sentenceBottom,sentenceCap)

tempstore=[" "]*numOfSentences
irregplrls={'child':'children','ox':'oxen','moose':'moose'}

def testforoo(x):
    return any(x[j]=='oo'.lower() for j in range(0,len(x)))

def pluralize(x):
    if x in irregplrls:
        return irregplrls[x]

    if x[-1]=="y":
        return x[:-1]+"ies"
    elif x[-2:]=="us":
        return x[:-2]+"i"
    elif x[-1] in 'sx':
        return x+"es"
    elif x[-2:] in ('ch','sh'):
        return x+"es"
    elif 'f'==x[-1] or x[-2]:
        if 'f'==x[-1]:
            return x[:-1] + 'ves'
        elif 'f'==x[-2]:
            return x[:-2]+"ves"
    elif any(x[j]=='oo'.lower() for j in range(0,len(x))):
        return x[:testforoo(x)-2]+'ee'+x[testforoo(x):]
    else:
        return x+'s'

print("\nRetrieving craploads of words...") 

verb=["moves","jumps", "hides","sniffs","gazes","sneezes","calls"]
noun=["rabbit","dog","cat","otter","seal","elephant","fox",'baby','moose','octopus']
adjec=["happy","angry","cute","enormous","elegant","annoying"]
adver=["merrily","frustratedly","incoherently","morosely","peppily",'exuberantly']
endpunct=[".","!"]

print("\nSimulating human grammar-speak...\n")

for i000 in range(0,numOfSentences):
    v=random.choice(verb)
    n=random.choice(noun)
    adj=random.choice(adjec)
    adv=random.choice(adver)
    pun=random.choice(endpunct)
    askinput=random.randint(0,round(numOfSentences/5))
    whichinput=random.randint(0,3)
    if askinput==0:
        if whichinput==0:
            n=input("Please input a noun. ")
        elif whichinput==1:
            v=input("Please input a verb. ")
        elif whichinput==2:
            adj=input("Please input an adjective. ")
        elif whichinput==3:
            adv=input("Please input an adverb. ")
    templates=["The %s %s %s %s%s" % (adj,n,v,adv,pun),
               "%s %s %s %s%s" % (adj,pluralize(n),v[:len(v)-1],adv,pun)]
    final = random.choice(templates)
    final=final[0].upper() + final[1:]
    tempstore[i000]=final
    print('numOfSentences==',numOfSentences,i000)

print("\nProducing proof of illiteracy...\n")

print ('\n'.join(tempstore))
```

I'm not sure of what the function `pluralize()` does, I let the function `testforoo()` and didn't try to modify this part, examine it carefully, the instruction `elif 'f'==x[-1] or x[-2]:` seems suspect to me, it must be `elif 'f'==x[-1] or 'f'==x[-2]:` in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful! However, every time the pluralize function is used, it prints None rather than a plural. It doesn't raise an error, though. How can I fix that?

Comment: To fix it, you should have taken in account what I wrote: the instruction ``elif 'f'==x[-1] or x[-2]:`` isn't good. It is equivalent to ``elif ('f'==x[-1]) or (x[-2]):``. There's nothing to say concerning ``'f' ==x[-1]``. But ``x[-2]`` is evaluated as a bool value; But in Python, every non-null object is evaluated to True. So when no otehr condition before ``elif ('f'==x[-1]) or (x[-2]):`` is verified, the program enters in this test and evaluates first ``if 'f' ==x[-1]`` and then ``elif 'f'==x[-2]``. However when ``'f'`` is neither the last or penultiem letter, none of these two conditions...

Comment: ...is verified. So the programs has, in this case no ``return`` to execute. When a function doesn't execute any return statement, it returns None.

Comment: Ok thanks! I was sure that I had tried    ‘f’==x[-1] or ‘f’==x[-2]    though. Hmmm...

Comment: I must draw your attention on an inconsistency that remaiend in my code but that came from your own code. In the ``testforoo')`` function, you wrote a test ``x[j:j+1]=='oo'.lower()`` bur ``x[j:+1]`` describes a string of length 1, that is to say one character only, while it is compared to the two characters string ``'oo'``. You must correct this inconsistency.

Answer (score 0):

If one or more of `n`, `v`, `adj`, or `adv` is not being assigned correctly, then its value is `None`. The line your error is on is concatenating strings together, but if one of the variables is not a string, it throws the error you're seeing.

Try printing the values of those variables at different places until you can track down exactly where the issue with their assignment lies.