# Django Google API Client Error..Trying to implement an application that adds events to a users google calendar after authentication

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-client-login

While using the OAuth authentication method I am unable to retrieve the authentication code from the url. Google redirects me to a url with code appended to its end

..I think I am making a mistake in the regex because after authenticating myself and giving the app the permission to manage my calendar I am redirected to 
http://127.0.0.1/Main/addloanpremium/?code=4/2wi1hu0Gv8YZuKo79kc-kjCmw7qj0W2EyLYa3qzIe7w# ..How do I extract the code from the url..The above url opens on a new tab and due to my urls.py displays the same form page however when I try to access the 'code' value using request.GET.get('code') it does not give any value..

Exception Value: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly

My views.py looks like:

```
def addloanpremium(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        loan=Loan()
        premium=Premium()
        user=request.user
        #form=loan_pre_form(request.POST)


        if(request.GET.get('typelp')=='loan'):
            loan.user=user
            #premium.user=user
            #lots of code here..all values from fields are stored into the db

            if(request.GET.get("iscalendar")=="True"):
                print(" \n \n entered iscalendar =true \n")

                print(" \n \n entered calendar now trying to add event \n \n")
                SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
                flow=auth2client.client.flow_from_clientsecrets('C:/Users/ghw/Desktop/Expenze/Main/client_secrets.json',SCOPES,redirect_uri='http://127.0.0.1:8000/Main/addloanpremium/')

                storage = oauth2client.file.Storage('credentials.dat')
                credentials = storage.get()

                if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
                    auth_uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
                    print("\n value of auth uri is "+auth_uri+"\n")
                    webbrowser.open(auth_uri)
                    auth_code = request.GET.get('code')
                    print("\n value of auth code is "+auth_code+"\n")
                    ### I am getting the auth code wrong
                    credentials = flow.step2_exchange(auth_code)

                    storage.put(credentials)
                http = httplib2.Http()
                http = credentials.authorize(http)
                CAL = build('calendar', 'v3', http=http)
                .
                .#lots of code here
                .
                return render(request,'Main/loan_pre_form.html',{})
```

my Main:urls.py:

```
url(r'^addloanpremium/$',views.addloanpremium,name='addloanpremium'),
```

my loan_pre_form.html contains

```
<form action=" {% url 'Main:addloanpremium' %}" method="GET">
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34715510/5832311), functions return a value and if you don't specify one, it will implicitly return `None`. **Exception Value: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly** error means that you try to use a `NoneType` as a string. I guess the problem is that this function doesn't return anything (in one case) so it actually returns `NoneType`.

Here is an [example](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/python) from Google documentation.

You can also check on these related threads:

- [Python 3.3.3 TypeError : Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20768021/python-3-3-3-typeerror-cant-convert-nonetype-object-to-str-implicitly)
- [TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654168/typeerror-cant-convert-int-object-to-str-implicitly)
- [Django: "Can't convert 'Name' object to str implicitly" on saving object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891872/django-cant-convert-name-object-to-str-implicitly-on-saving-object)

Hope this helps!